# Do you decline a multiplier in reading a mathematical formula in Russian?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation

How do you read "Порядок определителя равен $2n$"? Is it "двум эн" or is it "два эн"?

And in a sum, do you read $c = a_5 + a_6$ as "це равно а пятому плюс а шестому"? Or does the plus sign interfere with the declension in some way?

Comment: This is not a question about mathematics but about language...

Comment: @5xum How does this differ from this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916827/how-to-read-this-in-english

Comment: Or this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/how-can-i-read-this-mathematical-sentence-aloud-in-english Or this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660976/how-can-i-mathematically-read-this-map-fa-longrightarrow-b

Comment: It doesn't. Those questions should also be closed in my oppinion.

Comment: This is a question that math people are more likely to know the answer to. Particularly the second part, as people outside of mathematics have less experience with indices.

Comment: Look, if I am alone in my thinking, your question will be answered. I won't change my mind, but my close vote alone is not enough, so if you are right, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: It's funny that so many people on this site seem to take it for granted that a question can never be *both* about mathematics and about something else. Here's an argument. Do you think it is a question about mathematics if I ask: "How do you read $\iint_\Omega f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$"? Or is that also a language question only?

Comment: Obviously, it can be about both, but this one is not about mathematics as described in the help centre. Under which of the five categories do you think it belongs? (Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems, Hints on mathematical problems, History and development of mathematics , Solving mathematical puzzles, Software that mathematicians use)?

Comment: I don't think that list is meant to be exclusive. Otherwise, why is there a terminology tag?

Comment: well,  in Ukrainian it read as "два ен"  and "це   дорівнює a п'ять плюс а  шість"

Comment: Okay. In Russian you have the option of using either the number (два) or the adjective (второe), I think. For example, $a_k$ can be "а катое". Is that not right in Ukrainian?

Comment: As  rule the index  read  as  a number  not as a adjective

Comment: В принципе, пурист сказал бы «цэ равно сумме а-пятого и а-шестого». Но часто говорят «цэ равно а-пять плюс а-шесть» (что, разумеется, является некоторым жаргонизмом).

Comment: @GrigoryM That means that in this case, you would simply avoid using "а пятое", right? (I mean, if you're not a purist.) What about $2n$?

Comment: In this case too a purist would insist that only one variant is correct («двум эн») but in practice both variants are frequently used.

Comment: See related Meta discussion here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/questions-about-how-to-read-mathematical-notation

Comment: @GrigoryM Would you post this as an answer?

Comment: Dear user204305, I'm glad if my comments help — but it wouldn't be appropriate for me to post an answer to a question [I consider offtopic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19105/).

Answer (score 4):

Since Grigory M won't be posting an answer, I will post the answer I've received here, for future reference.

For the question about $2n$, it seems that the multiplying numeral $2$ can either be left invariable as "два" or put in the dative as "двум," with the latter option considered more correct by some people who have an opinion on the matter.

For $c = a_5 + a_6$, there are two options. Either retain the indices as adjectives by saying "це равно сумме а пятого и а шестого" ("$c$ is equal to the sum of $a$ the fifth and $a$ the sixth"), or, less elegantly, convert the indices to undeclined numerals as in "це равно а пять плюс а шесть" ("$c$ is equal to $a$ five plus $a$ six.") The reading "це равно а пятому плюс а шестому" ("$c$ is equal to $a$ the fifth [dat.] plus $a$ the sixth [dat.]") proposed in the OP is apparently not possible.